# How to resolve Nullpointer exception

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, testng

Here is my code:

**General.Java:**

```
package com.hrms.lib;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class General extends Global
{
//Open Application
    @Test
    public void openApplication()
    {
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.navigate().to(url);
    }
//Login
    @Test
    public void login() throws Exception
    {
     driver.findElement(By.name(txt_loginname)).sendKeys(un);
     driver.findElement(By.name(txt_password)).sendKeys(pwd);
     driver.findElement(By.name(btn_login)).click();
     Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

    @Test
    public void mouseover() throws Exception
    {
        elm=driver.findElement(By.linkText(NavigatePim));
        act=new Actions(driver);
        act.moveToElement(elm).build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    @Test
    public void mouseoverClick()
    {
        driver.findElement(By.linkText(Add_Emp)).click();
    }
//Enter Values in Textbox
    @Test
    public void save()
    {
        driver.findElement(By.name(txt_FName)).sendKeys(FName);
        driver.findElement(By.name(txt_LName)).sendKeys(LName);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText(btn_Save)).click();
    }
//Logout
    @Test
    public void logout()
    {

    driver.findElement(By.linkText(link_logout)).click();
    }
//Close Application
    @Test
    public void closeApplication()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

**Global.Java:**

```
 package com.hrms.lib;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
 import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
 public class Global 
{
    //Variables
    public WebDriver driver;
    public String url="http://opensource.demo.orangehrmlive.com/";
    public String un="admin";
    public String pwd="admin";
    public WebElement elm;
    public Actions act;
    public String FName="abc";
    public String LName="efg";

    //Objects
    public String txt_loginname="txtUsername";
    public String txt_password="txtPassword";
    public String btn_login="Submit";
    public String link_logout="Logout";
    public String NavigatePim="PIM";
    public String Add_Emp="Add Employee";
    public String txt_FName="firstName";
    public String txt_LName="lastName";
    public String btn_Save="Save";
}
```

**TC_101:**

```
package com.hrms.TestScripts;
import com.hrms.lib.*;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TC_Login_Logout 
{
    @Test
    public void tc() throws Exception
    {
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\Madhu\\Downloads\\geckodriver.exe");

       General Gl=new General();
       Gl.openApplication();
       Gl.login();
       Gl.mouseover();
       Gl.mouseoverClick();
       Gl.save();
       Gl.logout();
       Gl.closeApplication();
    }
}
```

I am getting Null pointer exception error while executing this test case. Could anyone explain why I am getting this error?

Comment: Welcome to SQA. Over here you are expected to solve the issue yourself still if you are not able to get the solution. Tells us what you have tried from your end. Describe you issue in detail. At which line are you getting the error. paste the stacktrace.

Comment: Actually the error message itself is more helpful than the code. As it always shows the linenumber that caused the exception. This way you should know where to look. Also try methods described here to resolve it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871825/a-good-way-to-debug-nullpointerexception

Comment: The error message would be very helpful. But I think all you need to do is get rid of the `@Test` annotation for all of your methods in the `General` class, to sum up my answer. Your `driver` would be `null` for all of those `@Test`s

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues, I'll try to explain the overall issues that will help point you in the right direction.

1. `@Test` represents an entire test to be run, but it appears you're using it as a test step, or a group of steps. This is your main issue.

******EDIT*****

I didn't look closely at your `TC_101` class, it looks like this is your actual test. All of your methods in your `General` class **should not** have the `@Test` attribute. Just remove `@Test` from those methods and try again.

******End EDIT*****

2. You need to use `@BeforeTest` and `@AfterTest` for things you want to happen before and after each `@Test`. For example, `driver=new FirefoxDriver();` would be in `@BeforeTest` and `driver.quit();` would be in `@AfterTest`

Currently as it is written, the only tests you have that don't start with the `driver` being `NULL` are `openApplication` and `tc`. The rest of your tests will fail right off of the bat with a `NullPointer`. The way the **Testng** test runner works, these objects don't persist between tests, and they also don't necessarily run in any particular order. This means your `openApplication` or your `tc` `@Test` will probably not run first.

Long story short... Make sure if you use the `@Test` annotation, that method has a path to run the entire test, from starting the driver, opening the startpage, to quitting the driver at the end. It should completely encapsulate an entire test and not just a few steps. `@BeforeTest` and `@AfterTest` are methods that will be included as part of that.

Answer (score 0):

I think The following code that you have mentioned in the TC_101 should be placed in the General Class in the openApplication() method.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\Madhu\\Downloads\\geckodriver.exe");
```